# Overriding method in C#

Tags: c#

I have a method which is fetching records from database based on their status.

Now I want to use the same method for fetching records by the id

Like:

```
public class A
{
    public List<Foo> GetDetails(bool IsActive)
    {
        return list; 
    }
}

public class B
{
    public List<Foo> GetDetails(int Id)
    {
        //Do something  
        return list; 
    }
}
```

So I don't want to write the same method again in class B.. I want to use the method of Class A here...

Comment: Well class B doesn't even derive from class A, so you can't override. Have you considered using composition, i.e. getting class B to *call* the method from class A? Your question is pretty unclear at the moment.

Comment: Let say i have inhertited A into B...

Comment: It is still unclear, what you try to achieve. When overriding a method, you have to re-implement the method body. But you are asking to use the same method. So you probably want to extract out some of the redundant logic into a separate method. Also you can only override with the same signature.

Comment: It's not clear why you want overriding at all. You really need to clarify your question...

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are not talking about method overriding, but about *overloading*:

- If you want to have several methods with the same name, but with different behaviours and different parameter list signatures, then we are talking about **method overloading**.
- If you have a base class with a virtual method, and you want to change the behavior of that method in a derived class, then we are talking about **method overriding**.

Then there is a third mechanism called **subclassing** by which the derived class inherits all data fields and behavior from the base class.

---

> **a.** If you want **method overriding**, be aware that your second method would have to have not just the same name, but also the same parameter types.

This doesn't apply here, since your two methods have different parameter types.

---

> **b.** If you want **method overloading**, just move your method into `A`:

```
public class A
{
    public List<Foo> GetDetails(bool IsActive)
    {
        …
    }

    public List<Foo> GetDetails(int Id)
    {
        …
    }
}
```

(Just be aware that if your `Foo` objects have another `bool` or `int` property by which you might want to query, overloading by itself will not work, because the overloading mechanism doesn't care about parameters' names, just about their types. As an example, you cannot have two methods `GetDetails(int id)` and `GetDetails(int frob)`.)

---

> **c.** If you want **subclassing**, i.e. `B` should inherit the original method from `A`, add this tiny bit to the declaration of `B`:

```
class B : A { … }
     // ^^^
```

Incidentally, this will also lead to your method(s) being overloaded in `B`, since there are now two methods in `B` having the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
public class B : A
{
    public List<Foo> GetDetails(int Id)
    {
        //Do something  
        return list; 
    }
}
```

Now class `B` also has the method `public List<Foo> GetDetails(bool IsActive)`.

Comment: I don't dispute that this is a working solution, but: assuming that we are talking about overriding (which is the reason why an inheritance relationship would be necessary at all in this case), how does this actually override any method in the base class?

Comment: @stakx - I don't think that the OP meant "overriding" - I think he meant "overloading".

Comment: Exactly. And if indeed he meant overloading, your solution is more complicated than it needs to be (as is the OP's final request). Just put the second method in `A`. No derived class required.

Comment: @stakx - The OP said he didn't want to rewrite `A`'s method in `B`. He didn't say put the method in `A`. Where are you reading that?

Comment: If we can be sure that the only inaccuracy in the OP's request is the wrong use of the term "overriding", then your answer is the perfect one; a combination of subclassing and method overloading. (I personally am not so sure this is the only inaccuracy, and therefore tend to suggest the simplest-possible solution.) +1 to your answer, in either case.

Answer (score 0):

You can move shared logic of DB accessing to one private method.
As example:

```
public class AB
{
    private List<Foo> GetDetailsByQuery(string query)
    {
       //excuting query
       return list;
    }

    public List<Foo> GetDetails(bool IsActive)
    {
        //creating query by isActive
        return GetDetailsByQuery(query);
    }

    public List<Foo> GetDetails(int Id)
    {
        //creating query by id
        return GetDetailsByQuery(query); 
    }
}
```